# Multiple instances on Microsoft Azure each with own IP address

Tags: azure

I want to run a web crawler on Microsoft Azure. Each web crawler instance should get an own IP address. What is a cost effective way to do this? Do I need virtual machines, workers roles or are web jobs sufficient?

Thank you

Comment: Cost-effective is subjective, as is the choice of using VMs vs cloud services. Regardless, this question should be posted to ServerFault, since it's not programming-related (it's infrastructure-related, about how Azure deals with IP address).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to recommend anything without knowing details of your project.

**WebJobs**

This is suppose to be the cheapest and easiest to use platform, in the other hand, it provides less control than cloud services or vms. If your project doesn't require anything special, webjobs should work and the only thing you have to worry about is sizing and scaling your hosting plan. You can have up to 10 large (4 cores, 7GB) instances in your webjob, should be more than enough for most needs.

Said that, one of your requirements is that each instance should have it's own VIP (Virtual Public IP). You won't have this possibility using webjobs. If you really can't afford using a single VIP, you will have to consider Cloud Services.

**Webjos Overview**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

**Cloud Services**

In Cloud Services, you always have one VIP but you can enable PIP (Instance level public IP) for each instance. There are a few limitations tho. You can only have 5 PIPs per subscription. If you need more, you'll have to ask Microsoft for it. The PIP cannot be reserved like the VIP, that way if you redeploy one of the instances or the entire project all your IPs will change. You can only reserve the standard VIP. Each PIP costs about $3/mo.

**Instance-Level Public IP Overview**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/

**IP Address pricing**

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/